# Считать ответ Http метода POST

Tags: c#, http, curl

Делаю запрос к сайту методом POST, указываю все заголовки, но в ответ мне приходит не понятные символы, проблема видимо с кодировкой, но я не понимаю как декодировать. Если посмотреть вкладку NetWork в хроме то в ResporceHeaders будет Content-Type = text/html; encoding UTF8;
Вот код пост запроса

```
using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient())
        {
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("method", "POST");
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("authority", "ru.pathofexile.com");
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("scheme", "https");
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("path", "/account/create");
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("cache-control", "max-age=0");
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("origin", "ru.pathofexile.com");
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("upgrade-insecure-requests", "1");
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("sec-fetch-mode", "navigate");
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("sec-fetch-user", "?1");
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("accept", "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3");
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("sec-fetch-site", "same - origin");
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("referer", "https://ru.pathofexile.com/account/create");
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("accept-encoding", "gzip, deflate, br");
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("accept-language", "ru-RU,ru;q=0.9,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.7,uk;q=0.6");
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("cookie", "__cfduid=daf1a2c54d70de6880302de97bb5742721555961118; _ga=GA1.2.1537561302.1555961122; stored_data=1; _gid=GA1.2.692957492.1565790558; cf_clearance=f19dc2acf3e2b2b53c9eac02e2d3d1c8bc23bf62-1565881976-300-150; _gat=1; POESESSID=d6d854a07c5ab8d8e25d4c1ccfea88d6");

            var values = new Dictionary<string, string>
{
   { "accountName", "Testaccount123321" },
   { "email", "testemail123321%40qf.com" },
   { "password", "123qwe" },
   { "passwordConfirmation", "123qwe" },
   { "captcha", "g-recaptcha-response" },
   { "g-recaptcha-response", CaptchaData.ToString() },
   { "dst", "0" },
   { "tzOffset", "-180" },
   { "acceptTerms", "1" },

};

            var content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(values);

            var response = await client.PostAsync("https://ru.pathofexile.com/account/create",content);

            string responseString = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            MessageBox.Show(responseString)



        }
```

Comment: Если вы добавите вывод - будет проще понять что у вас не так.

Comment: Может в `accept-encoding` стоит добавить-таки `utf-8`?

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/GBzjiQl вот такое в resporseString

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Изменение accept-encoding на UTF-8 все исправило. Задача решена

Comment: Таким решением вы отказались от сжатия трафика, можно было просто "разархивировать" ответ от сервера. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1581694/gzipstream-and-decompression

Comment: Если вопрос решён, то пометьте его как "решённый".